# Select alias in same select statement

Tags: sql, select, alias

```
    i.Notes, SUM(l.Discount) AS Dcount, i.DiscDate, i.DueDate, i.UIMth, i.UISeq, poj.Job, poj.Description, i.UniqueAttchID, i.ReviewerGroup AS RevGrp, SUM(l.GrossAmt) 
                     AS GrossAmt, v.PayTerms, dbo.HQPT.DiscRate, i.InvTotal, DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate) AS DiscDays,
--Trying to use the DiscDays and Dcount here    
                    if DiscDays, between '20' and '11' THEN sum(Dcount) as YelDisc
```

I am hoping someone can help me here. I am very new to T-SQL.  I believe what I need here is a sub Query but I'm not sure how to format it correctly

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference an alias within the same query but what you could do is the following:

```
      select
      i.Notes, 
      SUM(l.Discount) AS Dcount, 
      i.DiscDate, 
      i.DueDate, 
      i.UIMth, 
      i.UISeq, 
      poj.Job, 
      poj.Description, 
      i.UniqueAttchID, 
      i.ReviewerGroup AS RevGrp, 
      SUM(l.GrossAmt) AS GrossAmt, 
      v.PayTerms, 
      dbo.HQPT.DiscRate, 
      i.InvTotal, 
      DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate) AS DiscDays,

    --Trying to use the DiscDays and Dcount here    
        case
            when DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate)  between '11' and '20'                 THEN sum(Dcount) 
            when DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate)  between '20' and '40'         THEN sum(Dcount)/2 
            else 0 -- this is the default case that doesn't match your cases, it could return NULL 
        end as YelDisc
```

Comment: i added a few extra cases for clarification

Comment: Tudor thank you for your help, your suggestion worked just as I needed. The extra case statement was helpful. I do have one more question. How would the statement look if I wanted '11' and '20' to be YelDisc and '20' and '40' to be GreDisc? I know I can just can it all be dome within the same case statement or will I have to write one separately for the GreDisc? Thanks Again!!

Comment: You would have to put it on separate columns in separate case statemets as such:   `case
            when DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate)  between '11' and '20'                 THEN sum(Dcount) else null end as YelDisc, case when DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate)  between '20' and '40'         THEN sum(Dcount)/2 else null as GreDisc ` and look up the columns for not nulls in the where clause. The reason is that you your schema (i.e. column names and datatypes ) should not change depending on the data that is retrieved.

Comment: I rectified the query to use null instead of 0. 0 and null are different values but would work in this case. However, imagine a case when you sum up negative and positive values and get a total of 0.

Comment: the case statement is a powerful expressio that can be used in the select, on join clauses, on where clauses, on group by clauses and on having clauses. Not very common but there are cases when you want your query to behave differently when no values are found or values fall within a certain range. I recommend using clear indentation such that your case statements are very readable for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

1. `IF` is for program flow, not an expression
2. You can't reuse an alias in another column
3. When comparing numeric results do not surround constant values in quotes

try

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),i.DiscDate) between 20 and 11 
         THEN sum(Dcount) 
     ELSE 0 
END as YelDisc
```

You *could* do a subquery to reuse the alias, but for such a relatively simple expression and with the number of columns in your result set it's probably not worth it.

Comment: D Stanley thank you for your help. Your suggestion worked just as I needed. Cheers!!